# Java hashset how to serialise multiple objects

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, hashset

I asked a previous question about how I would save multiple save files to a .ser file, and I was suggested to use a hashset because they are serializable. I have tried to write a test piece of code to serialize every piece of information inside the hash set:

```
public class testHashSet {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        testClass new1 = new testClass("Hello", "male", true);
        testClass new2 = new testClass("Goodbye", "female", true);
        testClass new3 = new testClass("Something", "other", false);
        HashSet<testClass> hSet = new HashSet<testClass>();
        hSet.add(new1);
        hSet.add(new2);
        hSet.add(new3);
        System.out.println(hSet);
        for(int i = 0; i < hSet.size(); i++) {
            try {
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/Users/Prodigy958/Desktop/Hack_exeSaves.ser");
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
                out.writeObject(hSet(i));
                out.close();
                fileOut.close();
            } catch(IOException i) {
                i.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I'm having trouble with getting the code to write the object with index(i), because it says that that method is not defined for the type `HashSet`. Is there a way to iterate through every piece of information in the hash set or should I serialise the whole set all at once. A further question is that if the first answer is the latter, how would I go about deserialising the data into separate classes?

Comment: You can iterate over the set using `for(testClass item : hSet) { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: Serialize the hashset itself. Just make sure testClass implements Serializable and all of its fields do so to.

When you want to unserialize it and read the object, you cast it to `HashSet<testClass>` and it will maintain its state as before you serialized it.

Comment: if i serialised the whole hashset, what would happen when i unserialised it and tried to unserialise each "class object" into a separate class

Comment: @Shaydoth It will automatically unserialize all elements of the hashset. You can imagine when you serialize a object that it calls serialize on all of its members recursively. It serializes the same way. But make sure what you are trying to serialize implements Serializable

Comment: so you suggest that when I unseralise it, i should unserialise the data back into a hashset, and then turn each piece of the hashset into a class object again?

Comment: When you want to unserialize it and read the object, you cast it to (HashSet) and it will maintain its state as before you serialized it. @Shaydoth

Comment: And what would be the easiest way to turn the data from the hash set back into a class object? Because there are multiple different files should i create them back as classes by using an iteration for every item in the hash set? but how would the data in the hash set become an object?

Comment: @Shaydoth you don't need too, the objects will still be testClass objects after being deserialized. Just make sure testClass implements Serializable and all of its fields do so to.

Comment: @Shaydoth 'Turn each piece of the HashSet into a class object' is meaningless. That's what it already is when you deserialize it.

Comment: @EJP Thats not what I mean. I mean when i deserialise all the data into one hashset, how to i turn each of the pieces of deserialised data back into objects, because at the moment, all it does it deserialises it back into things like this: `[testClass@2503dbd3, testClass@4b67cf4d, testClass@330bedb4]`

Comment: What you mean doesn't mean anything. There is no 'piece of deserialized data'. There are only objects, and they have already been desetialized. There is nothing further left to do. The output you just provided is the result of `HashSet.toString()`. It doesn't prove anything.